# Is it possible to compare values of an element used multiple times?

Tags: xpath

I would like to take a value in the element `JobNumberString`, which is listed multiple times, and compare it to the previous `JobNumberString` to see if it is 1 digit higher?  Is this possible?
EXAMPLE:

```
JobNumberString [1] = 00
JobNumberString [2] = 01
JobNumberString [3] = 03
```

Give an Error, since this is not 1 higher than previous value.

Comment: Share `xml` sample for the same

Comment: Welcome to SO @mike! You don't show a lot of your xml (that's what you are likely talking about?). It is most probably possible but how it looks like exactly will depend more on the xml.

Comment: You need to specify which version of XPath you are using.